# How to Stub out Warden/Devise with Rspec in Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, capybara

I want to stub out a logged in user (with Devise/Warden) using rspec mocks in a Capybara test suite in my Rails app. This would save a ton of time, and would mean that my test suite can/will be run regularly.

Previously I was able to do this using authlogic by stubbing out my session model with some code like this:

```
def login(user)
  user_session = mock_model(UserSession, {:user => user})
  UserSession.stub(:find).and_return(user_session)
end
```

Now that i'm using Devise, i no longer have access to a UserSession object. And since i'm using capybara to test my code, i don't have direct access to the request object to use devise's built in `sign_in` test helper.

My question is: how can I simulate a logged in user with capybara, devise, and spec mocks without requiring every scenario with a logged in user to first go to the sign up path, fill in the form, submit, wait for response, and then go to the desired page?

Comment: Not what you asked, but just in case [login.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/spec/support/login.rb) and [sample_use.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/spec/requests/dashboard_issues_spec.rb)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've got something like that already that i'm trying to avoid. Though your comment is certainly helpful for those future visitors that might not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Warden comes with built in test helpers. It allows you to login without having to use the UI in your cucumber tests. Just add the files below into your project.

`# features/support/warden.rb`

```
Warden.test_mode!
World Warden::Test::Helpers
After { Warden.test_reset! }
```

`# features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb`

```
Given /^I am logged in as a user$/ do
  @current_user = User.create!(:username => 'user', :password => 'password')
  login_as(@current_user, :scope => :user)
end
```

[Use Wardens.test_mode! with Capybara](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Capybara)

Comment: I think this is the right direction, but can't quite get it to work. The helper methods get called correctly, but current_user et. al still aren't showing up correctly in my app. Does this work for you?

Comment: I needed to specify my current scope `login_as @current_user, :scope => :user` thanks for the help

Comment: Also thanks for linking to the capybara page, I actually ended up writing that ^_^ https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara/_history